H264 - how to interpret encoded video data
I would like to know how to interpret encoded video data by H.264 codec e.g. FFmpeg's AVPacket.data.
Are there any good resources about that to study?
I've been looking for the Internet, but I didn't find any documentation about H.264 format.
